# jest asynchronous test ignoring expect() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

server.js is a simple express.js file that uses jwt tokens. I currently want to test a simple route that will only return the string "Hello World" as shown below

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});
```

The code below is my jest file that is using supertest to send the request along with the valid jwt token

```
const supertest = require("supertest");

let server, request;
const serverStart = new Promise(resolve => {
  server = require("../server.js");
  request = supertest(server);
  server.on("app_started", () => {
    resolve();
  });
});

beforeAll(async () => {
  await serverStart;
});

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

describe("When testing the server.js", () => {
  it("Should connect successfully and be able to return a response", async () => {
    const response = await request
      .get("/")
      .set("Authorization", `bearer ${process.env.AUTHTOKEN}`);

    expect(response.text).toBe("Hello World");
    console.log(response.text);
  });
});
```

When running this jest (after it's timeout of 5 seconds) says `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified` however, the console.log that I have added after the expect function outputs "Hello World" to the console meaning the request is made and returns a value but it carriers on with the code but is just skipping the expect function

I've also tried this with `done()` and also using a `then()` but got the same error both times and I've console logged the time before and after the call and found it only takes a few milliseconds to return a value, so why does the expect not seem to complete the test?

Comment: shouldn't you be calling serverStart instead of just `await serverStart`? It should be `await serverStart()`

Comment: @AshishModi Why? It's a promise not a function.

Comment: @AjayDabas my bad. didn't realize that

Comment: @Blingdude I don't it's "skipping" the expected function. The unit test is just taking a longer time than the specified limit(default limit is 5000ms here). Try to increase the time limit to 10000ms maybe. You can do that in `it()` function like this: `it("",()=>{...},10000)`

Comment: Yeah I tried increasing the timeout to 30000 but it said the same message but with 30000 instead :/

Comment: Can you show `server.js`?  Where is this `app_started` event coming from?  I don't think that's an express built-in.

Comment: Try changing `app_started` to [`listening`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User zero298 pointed out that the test was failing during the `beforeAll()` function because `server.on()` wasn't returning anything. In the end I wrote the promise inside the **server.js** which resolves after it has started and then exported this promise.

```
let server;
const serverStart = new Promise(resolve => {
  server = app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
    resolve();
  });
});

module.exports = app;
module.exports.close = () => server.close();
module.exports.serverStart = serverStart;
```

and the `beforeAll()` in **server.test.js** now looks like

```
const server = require("../server.js");
let request;

beforeAll(async () => {
  await server.serverStart;
  request = supertest(server);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your problem is the `app_started` event that you are listening to.  I don't know where that event is documented.  I think you should use `listening` instead.  I'm going to make some assumptions about your **server.js** file.

The following test passes.  I think your tests never actually start because you are listening for an event that will never be fired.

This is the **server.js** file that I am testing with:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello");
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8081);

module.exports = server;
```

This is my test file **server.test.js**:

```
const supertest = require("supertest");

let server, request;

const serverStart = new Promise(resolve => {
    server = require("./server.js");
    request = supertest(server);
    server.on("listening", () => resolve());
});

beforeAll(async () => {
    await serverStart;
});

afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
});

describe("server", () => {
    it("should get hello", async () => {
        const response = await request.get("/");
        expect(response.text).toBe("hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: So I tried changing it to "listening" and also added a console log in the server.js that outputs "listening on port [portNumber]". It outputs the added console log and proceeds to give the same error after the async timeout.